# $f(x)=\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and $g(x)=\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about the following problem:

> Let $f(x)=\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}$ and $g(x)=\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then which of the following statements are correct?
>
> 1. $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x >0$,
> 2. $g$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$,
> 3. $g$ is a decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$,
> 4. $f$ is a decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$.

My attempt: I see that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)=0$ and so $f(x)=0$ when $x>0.$ Now I want to show that $f(x)>0$ when $x>0$. Also it is noticed that $f'(x)=g(x).$ But I am stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Tip: Instead of "sin\space", write "\sin" (and similarly "\cos" and "\lim").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- If $g(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$ then $f(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$.
- If $g'(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$ then $g(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$.
- If $g''(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$ then $g'(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$.
- Indeed, $g''(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$.
- Ergo.

Comment: +1 May I ask, what is Ergo?

Comment: Yes,I also want to know the same (what is "Ergo").

Comment: @BabakSorouh See [Cogito, ergo sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum). If this is distracting you, you may replace it by "QED".